# Python Extract URL (`where from`) information of downloaded image

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, opencv

I have downloaded an image from a website and I can see manually that the URL from which I have downloaded the image, appears in the image's information dialog window.

**I want to use python to extract the last part of this field i.e., `0001ss180819.png`.**

I have tried `PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image, ExifTags

img = Image.open("/Users/anonymous/Downloads/figs/image (1).jpeg")
exif = { ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v for k, v in img._getexif().items() if k in ExifTags.TAGS }
```

**but I cannot manage to get the desired information i.e., `where from` field as shown below.**

**My goal is to rename the photos based on this information.**

[image: on]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url from where the file was downloaded is not inside the image itself but as an extended attribute (that is from macOS). See https://superuser.com/questions/214934/how-can-mac-os-x-save-details-about-the-url-from-which-a-file-has-been-downloade

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So there is no way to do it using python?

Comment: You could run `xattr` and `mdls` to extract that info from Python if you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Just for the record,** I have managed to find a solution to do this within python:

```
from subprocess import call
import os, numpy as np

path = "/Users//Downloads/photos/"
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path)]
n_images = len(files)

for i in range(n_images):
    full_file_path = os.path.join(path + files[i])
    tmp = os.popen("mdls -name kMDItemWhereFroms '{}'".format(full_file_path)).read()
    ID = tmp.split('file=')[-1].split('.')[0].split('ss')[0]
    new_name = '/Users//Downloads/photos/' + ID + '.jpeg'
    call(["mv", "{}".format(full_file_path), "{}".format(new_name)])
```